# plogger navi links

Tags: navigation, hyperlink

Is it possible to add plogger navi links over the photos?

Like:

```
Category -> SubCategory -> SubCategory?
```

Comment: Do you mean like a watermark, subtitles or like left/right buttons sitting over the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to drop

```
<?php echo generate_breadcrumb(); ?>
```

..into your template file?

Answer (score 0):

I had to modifify theme... i was only improving portal, and plogger theme was very modified.